# Normalize generalised normal distribution

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

Could you please give a hint how to prove that the generalised normal distribution is normalised?

\begin{align}
p(x\mid\mu,\alpha,\beta) = \frac{\beta}{2\alpha\Gamma(\frac{1}{\beta})}e^{-(|x-\mu|/\alpha)^\beta}
\end{align}

Such that:

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} p(x\mid\mu,\alpha,\beta)\,dx = 1
\end{align}

Comment: Hint: Using the change of variable $t=x^\beta$, one gets $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^\beta}dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\beta^{-1}t^{\beta^{-1}-1}dt=\beta^{-1}\Gamma(\beta^{-1})$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the absolute value, this is often called a [Generalized Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution), which gives a hint to the solution: a Gamma variate $X$ has been shifted to a mean $\mu$ (which will not change the normalization constant), rescaled by $\alpha$ (which divides the normalization constant by $\alpha$, as you can see), and then takes the $\beta \gt 0$ power.  The absolute value introduces a mirror image of the distribution on the negative reals, whence we need to divide by $2$.

That shows we only need to check that the integral

$$I(\beta)=\int_0^\infty \exp(-u^\beta) du$$

equals $\frac{1}{\beta} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{\beta}\right)$ and strongly suggests the substitution $v=u^\beta$, whence $$du = d(v^{1/\beta}) = \frac{1}{\beta}v^{1/\beta-1}dv$$ and

$$I(\beta) = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\beta}v^{1/\beta-1} e^{-v}dv = \frac{1}{\beta} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{\beta}\right),$$

*QED*.